# How to get previous page javascript

Tags: javascript, php

```
   echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
           window.alert('Succesfully Updated')
           </SCRIPT>");
```

this is my code i want it to redirected in my previous page and had it refresh.

Comment: What are you trying to do say clearly

Comment: i want window.location and be directed to my previous page and already refresh

Comment: If using PHP then use HTTP_REFERER

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<script>
window.location = document.referrer;
</script>
```

Comment: what if 2 previous page? thankss

Comment: With refresh, I don't think you can do that, since document.referrer only refers to the URL where you came from to your current url. You can go back two pages by window.history.go(-2), but that won't refresh the page, and for security reasons, you can't get the URLs from window.history: if you could get previous URLs, you could possibly steal session tokens that were kept in the address bar.